# Use a dataset array without Statistics Toolbox

Tags: matlab

At my workplace I have one license of MATLAB on a virtual machine, which has Statistics Toolbox included with it. I like to use that instance of MATLAB to import csv data into dataset arrays, because of the convenience it provides.

However, I'd like to use the imported data on my local machine, which has its own license for MATLAB but (unfortunately) no Statistics Toolbox.

What is the best way to convert the dataset object to something that can be used with only base MATLAB? `dataset2struct`? It seems that if I'm just converting it back to a structure, I might as well just write a function that imports the data directly to a structure. Or is there any other way to work with dataset array in a MATLAB instance that lacks Statistics Toolbox?

Answer (score 2):

In version 13b of MATLAB (out this September, prerelease is available now), there will be something similar to a dataset array in base MATLAB called a `table` data container (I haven't tried it yet, and can't be sure it will be exactly the same). Also a `categorical` array similar to that currently in Statistics Toolbox.

Until then, there's not really a way to use a dataset array without Statistics Toolbox, and I would suggest either of the two methods you mention (personally I'd go with just using a structure throughout, as I find the convenience of dataset arrays to be overrated - but that's just my experience, yours may differ).

Comment: I'll give it a try and let SO know how these look!